# android: Unable to access struct static data members

Tags: android, c++

I'm having the next kind of error when linking the application:

```
undefined reference to 'MyStructure::K_VARIABLE_A
undefined reference to 'MyStructure::K_VARIABLE_B
...
```

The structure is defined inside "MyStructure.h" as:

```
struct MyStructure
{
const static int K_VARIABLE_A=1;
const static int K_VARIABLE_B=2;
...
}
```

How can i get rid of this error?

My source code compiles successfully for Windows platform but I get the error mentioned above when compiling for the android platform.

The header of this structure is properly included in the .cpp file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to define constant values in the scope of a class/struct is this:

```
struct MyStructure
{
    enum
    {
        K_VARIABLE_A=1,
        K_VARIABLE_B=2,   // Note that you CAN keep the trailing comma
        ...
    };
};
```

Comment: Hey! thanks!, I tried this solution and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The construct which you are using is called as **In-Class Initialization**. It is a valid syntax for *integral constant types* but it maynot work with some compilers.

Solution is to do:

```
const int MyStructure::K_VARIABLE_A=1;
const int MyStructure::K_VARIABLE_B=2;
```

in one of your cpp(Implementation) files.

Comment: actually I believe that it won't work with most compilers (actually I don't know of a compiler that In-Class Initialization does work for static members), semantics I know but...

Comment: @diverscuba23: It works for the OP on windows and syntactically it is actually valid.

Comment: I believe it's required by the standard to work as long as you don't perform any operation that requires an address.  As long as you just use it by value, I think it's required to work.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yup thats correct, As long as you don't take the address of the member with In-Class Initialization, it should work, but some compilers do *incorrectly* insist on the definition.

Comment: @als: yep, and also apparently with newer g++ compilers. learn something new every day. last time I tried with the g++ compilers was back with g++ 2.95.x series and haven't played with it since.

Answer (score 1):

For each of your static variables you will need to declare them in an compilation unit (traditionally .cpp file) so that they have storage space as such

```
#include "Mystructure.h"

const int MyStructure::K_VARIABLE_A = 1;
const int MyStructure::K_VARIABLE_B = 2;
// other stuff here...
```

This is because static members do not belong to any instance of the structure/class, but need storage space declared somewhere. The compilers leave it up to the programmer to specify which compilation unit contains the storage for the static members, but traditionally they will be placed in the .cpp file corresponding to the .h file.